# C++ code not showing output when array size is to large(eg. size >= 800) but working fine in online compiler

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, data-structures

I don't understand why this is happening.

The Code is working fine, but it won't show output in my system when I take a large array size and on the other side it gives the correct output in the online compiler.

It works fine and shows output in my system if I take a small array size.

```
#define N 805
```

Here is a code in C++ language.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
 
#define fast_io ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);cin.tie(NULL);
#define M 1000000007
#define N 805
#define ll long long int
 
void init_start(){
    fast_io;
    #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    #endif
}
 
int main()
{
    init_start();
    int n, k, limi;
    cin>>n>>k;
    
    int n_arr[N][N];
    int k_arr[N][N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        k_arr[i][0]=0;
        k_arr[0][i]=0;
    }
 
    int mini = -1, maxi = 1000000000, mid;
    bool check;
    limi = ((k*k) / 2) + 1;
 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            cin >> n_arr[i][j];
        }
        
    }
     while((mini + 1) < maxi)
     {
        mid = (mini + maxi) / 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            {
                k_arr[i+1][j+1] = k_arr[i+1][j] + k_arr[i][j+1] - k_arr[i][j];
                if(n_arr[i][j] > mid)
                {
                    k_arr[i+1][j+1]++;
                }
            }
        }
        check = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < n-k+1; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n-k+1; ++j)
            {
                if ((k_arr[i+k][j+k] + k_arr[i][j] - k_arr[i][j+k] - k_arr[i+k][j])<limi)
                {
                    check = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (check)
            {
                maxi = mid;
            }
            else
            {
                mini = mid;
            }
     }
     cout << maxi << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For perspective, a 2-d array of 4-byte ints of size 805x805 is ~2.5 MB.

Answer (score 3):

```cpp
int n_arr[N][N];
int k_arr[N][N];
```

I suspect your local environment is configured with a smaller stack size that the online one. With `N` set to `805`, and with 32-bit integers, that's going to consume about 5M of stack, quite a lot.

You may want to think about using the heap, which is usually less restrictive (`new` and `delete`). An easy solution is to keep the first dimension on the stack (805 pointers is not too bad) but use the heap for the second dimension, something like:

```cpp
int *n_arr[N], *k_arr[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    n_arr[i] = new int[N];
    k_arr[i] = new int[N];
}

// Use them here as you currently do, e.g., n_arr[42][99].

for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    delete [] n_arr[i];
    delete [] k_arr[i];
}
```

A *better* solution for C++ would probably be to use `std::vector`, or find/create a heap-based matrix class of some description.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> #include<bits/stdc++.h>
> ```

Avoid abusing implementation defined headers. The purpose of this header is to use in pre-compiled headers.

> ```
> using namespace std;
> ```

Avoid using this in the namespace scope. Prefer using the scope resolution operator instead.

> ```
> #define fast_io ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);cin.tie(NULL);
> ```

Avoid obfuscating the program like this. Prefer using a function instead.

> ```
> #define M 1000000007
> #define N 805
> ```

Avoid using macros for constants. Prefer (constant) variables instead.

> ```
> #define ll long long int
> ```

Avoid using macros for type aliases. Prefer `typedef`/`using` instead.

Just avoid using macros altogether unless there are no better alternatives (and there usually is).

Also, prefer to avoid using type aliases altogether except for template purposes. `long long` isn't that much to type, and it is immediately obvious to a reader what type it is.

---

The size available for automatic variables is typically very limited on most systems. You should avoid large automatic objects since those will likely result in a... *stack overflow*.

> ```
> int n_arr[N][N];
> ```

This is an automatic variable. And it is huge. It is very likely to overflow the stack on some systems. Avoid doing this.

For this program, the simplest solution is to use static storage instead of automatic.